# Comparing two dates in grouped variable

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, date-comparison

I am trying to compare two dates but I get the error "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"
I also tried using iloc and .values as some other questions were answered using this method but I get various other errors using that. 
I am not sure what to do. The issue is where I write:

```
 elif group[1]["dtstart"] <= endDate
```

Below is my full sample code.

Note that this is not the actual data I am working with, I tried to make it very similar. I still get the same error for both (Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects),

BUT when I include the .values in this code (with the fake data) in this section like so `group[1]["dtstart"] <= endDate.values` I get the error: `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`When I include .values in the same location in the real data I get the error: "Lengths must match to compare"
which was why I tried the iloc and still didn't succeed. I am not even sure if iloc or .values is the way to go and the fake data and the real data don't produce the same error when I include either, but just keeping everything as is produces the same error in both the fake and real which is

"Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
#Create a DataFrame
d = {
    'ID':[1,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,4,4],
   'dtstart':[pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2018-01-30'), pd.Timestamp('2018-03-01'), pd.Timestamp('2018-03-14'),
               pd.Timestamp('2018-04-08'), pd.Timestamp('2018-04-27'), pd.Timestamp('2018-07-03'), pd.Timestamp('2018-07-17'),pd.Timestamp('2018-07-17'),pd.Timestamp('2018-01-20')],
   'dtend':[pd.Timestamp('2018-01-06'), pd.Timestamp('2018-02-15'), pd.Timestamp('2018-03-05'), pd.Timestamp('2018-03-22'),
               pd.Timestamp('2018-04-15'), pd.Timestamp('2018-05-06'), pd.Timestamp('2018-07-07'), pd.Timestamp('2018-07-28'),pd.Timestamp('2018-01-18'),pd.Timestamp('2018-01-22')]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

grouped = df.groupby(['ID'])
grouped.apply(lambda _df: _df.sort_values(by=['dtstart']))
count=0
df_CE = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'dtstart', 'dtEnd'])
for group in grouped:
    months_enrolled=len(group)
    if count == 0:
        print("group[1][dtstart]===",group[1]["dtstart"])

        startDate = group[1]["dtstart"]
        endDate   = group[1]["dtend"] 
        count += 1
#    print("endDate==",TEST_endDate.dtypes)
    elif group[1]["dtstart"] <= endDate:
        print("yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

You never set `grouped.apply(lambda _df: _df.sort_values(by=['dtstart']))` to anything. If you wanted to sort it and keep it as sorted, then you should change it to

```
grouped = grouped.apply(lambda _df: _df.sort_values(by=['dtstart']))
```

That makes `grouped` a multiindexed DataFrame, and you will need to iterate as such. Assuming you didnt want to do that, you are getting an error because you are comparing two `pd.Series` of different length. I ran your code, and at line where you get that error, the comparison was made between

```
(4,    ID      dtend    dtstart
8   4 2018-01-18 2018-07-17
9   4 2018-01-22 2018-01-20)
>>> g2
(2,    ID      dtend    dtstart
1   2 2018-02-15 2018-01-30
6   2 2018-07-07 2018-07-03
7   2 2018-07-28 2018-07-17)
```